# Service class onStartCommand() method's return value

Tags: android, service

I was re-reading the Service documentation and something drew my attention on the return values of the onStartCommand() method.

The thing is if you return START_NOT_STICKY for example, and if you have "pending start commands" the service is re-started if it'd be killed by the system. That's totally OK except one thing. What's the "pending start commands" here? More precisely, how there exist "pending start commands" since it's not possible to call startService() out of main thread?

The only thing comes to my mind is startService gets called and put into the tail of the main thread's (Looper's) event queue and before it gets executed, service is destroyed and leaves the event queue with "pending start command(s)".

Do you think am I totally lost or on the correct path?

Answer (score 3):

One of the parameters passed to `onStartCommand()` is an `int` identifying this command (typically called `startId`). That `startId` can be passed to `stopSelf()`. Whereas the zero-parameter `stopSelf()` says "I am done with this service", the one-parameter `stopSelf(int)` says "I am done with this command and all commands that have preceded it".

So, suppose we have this series of events:

- `onStartCommand()` called with a `startId` of 1
- `onStartCommand()` called with a `startId` of 2
- `onStartCommand()` called with a `startId` of 3
- `stopSelf()` called with a `startId` of 2
- the process is terminated

Here, if your return value from `onStartCommand()` has been `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, Android will start up your process again (when memory conditions improve), so that you can do whatever `startId` of 3 was.

`START_NOT_STICKY` says "if you terminate my process due to low memory conditions, and memory improves, that's OK, I'll stay dead, until there is some new command to process".

Comment: I don't think I fully got you. Actually I understand what you've told and it's totally acceptable. However, in the documentation, there's this "the pending request" phrase keeps confusing me. It feels like there must be some "start service requests" around  and they're waiting to be executed right before before the process gets ripped apart. When I look at your response (the series of events basically), I see onStartCommand method executions were already done, right?. So it seems there's nothing "pending". Do I make my self clear?

Comment: @zgulser: "they're waiting to be executed right before before the process gets ripped apart" -- mostly, that would be `startId` 3 from my answer. "I see onStartCommand method executions were already done, right?" -- no. If you are using anything other than `START_NOT_STICKY`, a command is not done *until you say that it is done* via a call to `stopSelf(int)`, passing the `startId` of the command (or of a later command). The expectation is that you will be processing those commands on a background thread (see `IntentService`) and will tell Android when you are done with each.

Comment: Um, by saying "done", I meant returning from onStartCommand(). Sorry for the confusion. However, I still don't get why we're focusing on stopSelf only here? I mean when the process gets killed by the system, each command is destroyed along with the service regardless of command id or start order. In this case which one of them would be the "pending command" and gonna get re-started assuming it's return value is can be both START_STICKY or START_NOT_STICKY?

Comment: @zgulser: "I still don't get why we're focusing on stopSelf only here" -- it is how you say that you are done processing a command. "each command is destroyed along with the service" -- no. Information about the pending commands is held in a core OS process. "assuming it's return value is can be both START_STICKY or START_NOT_STICKY?" -- if you mix-and-match return values from `onStartCommand()`, I have no idea what to expect.

Comment: @zgulser: "what happens when the process gets terminated when executing onStartCommand?" -- I have no idea. I have not attempted to simulate that scenario, and it's not documented AFAIK.